# Bootstrapのiconとlink_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrapのiconをボタンにしたいのですが、うまい事使用することが出来ません。
文字ではなく、bootstrapのベルのiconだけのボタンにしたいのですが、classにbi bi-bellを含めても表示されません。
link_toには違ったコードの書き方なのでしょうか？

```
<div class="notification_navbar">
    <% if @notification.presence %>
        <div class="cecked-false">
            <p class="ms-3 cecked-false-mark "><%= link_to '通知', notifications_path, class: 'nav-link plan-nav cecked-false-link'%></p>
        </div>
    <% else %>
        <p class="ms-3"><%= link_to notifications_path, class: 'nav-link plan-nav' { %><i class="bi bi-bell"></i><% } %></p>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

bootstrap/icon
https://icons.getbootstrap.jp/icons/bell/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`link_to`でリンクを作成するとき、単純な文字列ではなく、タグを使用する必要がある修飾された文字列やアイコンや画像などやそれらの組合せをリンクにしたい場合はブロックを使用します。

```
<p class="ms-3">
  <%= link_to notifications_path, class: 'nav-link plan-nav' do %>
    <i class="bi bi-bell"></i>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

上記のようにブロックの内側でタグを書くとその部分がリンクになります。

参考: [ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper#link_to](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

Comment: 大変申し訳ありません。<p class="ms-3"><%= link_to '通知', notifications_path, class: 'nav-link plan-nav' %><i class="bi bi-bell"></i></p>で試してみたのですが、表示されませんでした。また、<p class="ms-3"><%= link_to '通知', notifications_path, class: 'nav-link plan-nav' { %><i class="bi bi-bell"></i><% } %></p>ではエラーになってしまいました。クラスの最後はカンマが必要ですか？

Comment: すいません。第一引数を消し忘れてました。回答を修正してます。第一引数の代わりにブロックを使うということです。

Comment: 申し訳ありません。<p class="ms-3"><%= link_to notifications_path, class: 'nav-link plan-nav' { %><i class="bi bi-bell"></i><% } %></p>でもエラーが発生しました。質問に追記させて頂いたのですがif文がエラーの原因になっているのでしょうか？

Comment: 一行に収まるようにしてしまったのが駄目だったのかも知れません。再度回答のコードを複数行で書くように変更してみました。もし、これでもダメだったときは、エラー内容がわからないと難しいです。

Comment: エラーは起こらなかったのですが、ベルマークが表示されませんでした。BootStrapのバージョンが悪いのでしょうか？バージョン：<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

Comment: `<i class="bi bi-bell"></i>`とだけしてもベルマークのアイコンが表示されなければ、Boostrap Iconsが使えるように設定されていません。Bootstrap IconsはBootstrapとは別の独立したパッケージであるため、Boostrapを使えるようにしてもBootstrap Iconsが使えるようにはなりません。使えるようにするためのインストール方法などの詳細は[Bootstrap Icons Install](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/#install)を確認してください。もし、うまくいかない等があれば、別の問題ですので、別の質問として質問してください。

Comment: もし、Bootstrap Iconsをインストールするのが難しいというのであれば、SVGをそのまま使うという方法もあります。`<i class=... ></i>`の部分をアイコンの詳細ページに書いてある`<svg xmlns=... </svg>`というSVGコードに置き換えてみてください。使うアイコンが一つ程度あれば、こちらの方が簡単です。

Comment: cdnのやり方で表示されました！ありがとうございます。